# Passing class object to second window wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've searched around online quite a bit and have come up short. How can I pass an instance of a class object to a second popup window and return the changes only if the user clicks ok.

For example say you have a list of people and when you double click a person in the list an edit window appears. In the edit window would be a textbox displaying the person's name where users could change it. The change would only be committed back to the main view model if the user hits the 'OK' button. Otherwise the changes would be dismissed. Ideally this edit window would be modal.

How can I do this?

Comment: When you create the instance of the new window just pass it in through the constructor. Then only commit changes when the ok button is pressed.

Comment: sounds easy but im not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a person object that you want to modify called Joe so: `public Person Joe = new Person();` When you create your new window just say `NewWindow window = new NewWindow(Joe);`. Then in your NewWindow Constructor let it accept a person object like so

```
Person aPerson;
NewWindow(Person inPerson)
 {
     aPerson = inPerson
 }
```

Now when the user clicks on the save button modify whatever fields of aPerson that you need to modify. You can use something like an event to send it back to the original view. Would have put this in a comment, but the code blocks make it easier to read.